# Sas filter macro

Tags: sas

Hi I have a macro which designed to accept only one filter value however I want make it multiple input comma separated value code. Please help. `data new (where name =John, David, Ralph)`

Comment: Why do want commas in the call?  Why not just have them pass the values using space or some other character that is not part of the syntax of a macro call?

Comment: @tom can space solve the problem, could u please help how space can solve problem. That is not an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct `where=` option would be

```
data new (where=(name in ('John', 'David', 'Ralph'));
```

Are you prepared to pass your macro a comma separated list of quoted values?

What does the current macro look like ?

Suppose the macro accepts one unquoted value:

```
%macro my_macro (name);
  data new (where=(name="&name"));
    set sashelp.class;
  run;
%mend;

%my_macro (Alfred)
```

The changed macro, accepting a quoted list of values would require `%STR('value-1', ..., 'value-n' )` in the macro call in order to mask the commas.  Unmasked, each value would be considered a separate argument.

```
%macro my_macro (names);
  data new (where=(name in (&names)));
    set sashelp.class;
  run;
%mend;

%my_macro (%str('Alfred', 'Jane'))
```

The SAS in operator allows the list of values to be space separated, so this invocation would also work.

```
%my_macro ('Alfred'  'Jane')
```

If you want the name values to be unquoted when you pass them in you have to do more coding.  The `PARMBUFF` `%macro` options will let your code access an automatic variable `syspbuff` that is everything after the macro name.

So the invocation

```
%my_macro (Alfred, Jane, Authur)
```

would cause `syspbuff` to be

```
(Alfred, Jane, Authur)
```

See the documentation [%MACRO Macro Statement - Example #3](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=p1nypovnwon4uyn159rst8pgzqrl.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) that shows how a `%DO` loop and `%SCAN()` are used to to parse values out of `SYSPBUFF`

Before going down that rabbit hole, ask yourself "What if the filter value itself needs to contain comma"? The 'simple' contract of unquoted values all of a sudden becomes a headache.  The callee would need to mask commas with `%str`

```
%my_macro (Alfred,William,Wayne%str(,)Bruce,%str(Grayson, Dick))
```

Flipping the problem around, you can pass a delimited list of *match any of these* values, and then use a function such as `FINDW` to check for a match

```
%macro my_macro (names);
  data new (where=(FINDW("&names",trim(name),'|')));
    set sashelp.class;
  run;
%mend;

%my_macro (Alfred|Jane)
```

Comment: Macro goes like %str names = ( )   this will come from user with simple name values and it has cappibility to except one name. Now I want that user can give multiple values with comma separated values as listed above

Comment: Hi @Richard user will pass unquoted comma separated names. Please if you could help with that approach.

Comment: Note that the IN operator in SAS does not need commas. Spaces are acceptable as delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier with macro calls to use something other than comma as the delimiter.  Space for example.  Or some other character that will not appear in the values being passed, like `|` or `^`, that does not have special meaning to the macro processor like a comma does.

The `IN` operator in SAS does not need commas between the values, spaces will work.

For strings you might want to add the quotes in the macro.

```
%macro my_macro(list);
   %local qlist;
   %let qlist="%sysfunc(tranwrd(&list,%str( )," "))";
   proc print data=sashelp.class;
     where name in (&qlist);
   run;
%mend my_macro;
%my_macro(Alfred Alice);
```

But for numbers the quotes are not needed so it is easier.

```
%macro my_macro(agelist);
   proc print data=sashelp.class;
     where age in (&agelist);
   run;
%mend my_macro;
%my_macro(12 13);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your support @tom

Comment: Hi @Tom let suppose if user gives the comma values can I later replace it with any other delimiter. If you could please help me with that logic

Comment: If you just want to use the list in IN operator then commas or spaces work the same. If the user succeeds in passing in a comma delimited list of unquoted values, for example by using %STR() in the macro call, you could probably figure out how to modify the FROM argument of the TRANWRD() function call to handle that. In either case watch out for extra spaces between the items in the list.